# LVM2: extended logical volume, but cannot run e2fsck because logical volume is mounted

Tags: lvm

I extended a logical volume while it was mounted using 'lvextend' and that completed successfully. I then attempted to run 'e2fsck -f' but received a warning about the filesystem being mounted and that this would cause severe filesystem damage.

So I ran 'umount -l' to unmount, and then attempted to run 'e2fsck -f', but that fails to run because the logical volume "is in use".

So I'm in a halfway position where the logical volume is extended, but the filesystem has not been resized to fill the newly extended logical volume. How do I proceed without losing the data?

Answer (score 1):

Got it figured out. I ran 'fuser -m' on the mount point and that returned the process id number of the process that was accessing the filesystem. I then ran 'kill' on the process id number.

From there, I was able to 'umount', then 'e2fsck -f' ran successfully. Then ran 'resize2fs' to finish.